# Changing locks on server cabinet

Tags: physical

I work in higher education, and we have a server room with various server cabinets, mostly APC and Belkin.  The room is secured via card swipe access, however each server rack has the same lock, which presents a problem as this room serves the college.  I have searched high and low, and cannot seem to find a straight forward solution.  There are a few racks we would like to ensure are secure only to our department, by changing out all of the locks on the server racks.  What is the best, easiest, quickest, most cost effective way to go about this?  They all have swing handled locks on the front and back of the rack doors, and a lock on each side panel.  Thanks for you input!

Comment: The *easiest* thing to do would be to move your cabinets to a different room, under a different swipe card. However you have to consider your thread model; just about every 'hacker' type I know is also reasonably proficient at picking locks, and server cabinets have pretty terrible locks.

Comment: Easiest, quickest, most cost-efficient way is to call a locksmith and ask him to change the core of the lock. Last time I checked, they go under $10 each.

Comment: The answer to this will be different depending on what type of locks are installed on the server racks, and the manufacturer of the locks/racks. More detail will be needed to make this an answerable question. However, as @lynks points out, threat modeling is also important. Locks on the server cabinet are like picket fences - they keep the honest people honest, but do little against a determined and skilled attacker.

Comment: Who currently has access to this room via swipe card and why do they have access? That is the first question I would be asking.

Comment: Other professors and some students who work with these professors, but not necessarily under immediate supervision.  Being that our purpose is education, there are some things we just have to accept to promote "learning" such as these students with access.  Again, I don't think there would be any malicious intent, more of snooping and something inadvertently occurring and us not knowing about it immediately.  This rack holds production servers for courses, and it would just ease our minds a bit to know only we had access to them.

Comment: Then, as @lynks said, I would definitely recommend moving them to a different room. I wouldn't want critical production servers anywhere *near* an area that college students have access to - "supervised" or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

From a security standpoint,  most locks are very easy to bypass.  The design for [Pin-tumbler locks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pin_tumbler_lock) date back to 4000 BC in Egypt.  Although server locks are [easy to purchase](http://www.sellntell.com/cabinet_handle_locks.htm).   I am not aware of a "high security" locks for servers.

The **BEST** approach is to limit access to the data center.  If you cannot do that,  then move sensitive servers to the cloud.

Comment: I spoke to my boss about having a locksmith change the locks, since we are in a Univ, clearly there is a locksmith available. We recently had rewiring down to allow cable access to a host for an election study, and that cost the department over $600.00. He is leaning towards replacing the locks simply at a hardware store and installing them ourselves. Our main servers are housed in our office where only we have access, but it's simply impractical w/ the amount of room/ips to host more in our central location.  We may just take our chances.  These servers aren't essential for dept function.

Comment: Again, it is not that these hosts need massive security, it is to prevent any standbyers  idling with our equipment.  If you work in govmt or education, you know how hard it is to get something approved through the budget committee... this is simply to alleviate our worries that curious students would tamper with our racks in attempt to mirror their projects, but VM's for student courses are not as essential as our operations, and can always be restored w/ backups if need be.  Maybe we'll buy a bicycle lock and wrap it around the rack :)

Comment: Using the cloud for security just trades known security problems for ones the cloud provider doesn't tell you about...

Comment: I would not put much faith in a PCI assessment. As a provider of services, that would not necessarily mean your app sitting on top is coded securely, etc. When hosting providers becomes have a ROC issued, it might not always cover all areas completely, it just a convenience to streamline some of the network stuff for when clients want to certify. I believe Amazon may have some type of SOC2 which they share with only their biggest clients. And yes, most universities have just learned about security never.

Comment: I hate answers like these. I want to +1 for "limit access to the datacenter" but -1 for "move sensitive servers to the cloud".

Comment: @Iszi the cloud is still safer than a university data-center.  At-least a cloud provider like AWS is certified.